# Setting xlim for Pandas DataFrame plot

Tags: python, pandas

I'm plotting a stacked bar plot from a `Pandas DataFrame`. The index dates are in `datetime` format and plot just fine. The issue I'm having is trying to set `xlim` values.

```
day_counts = {'a': count_a,
              'b': count_b,
              'c': count_c,
              'd': count_d}

df_days = pd.DataFrame(day_counts, index=date)
```

The variables `count_a`, .., `count_d` are lists of numbers and `date` is a list of `datetime` objects.

Plotting without an xlim parameter gives:
[image]

Plotting with xlim attempt 1:

```
ax = df_days.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True,
                  xlim=[pd.Timestamp('2015-09-01'), pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01')])
```

Plotting with xlim attempt 2:

```
ax = df_days.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
ax.set_xlim(pd.Timestamp('2015-09-01'), pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01'))
```

Plotting with xlim attempt 3:

```
ax = df_days.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
ax.set_xlim(datetime.datetime(2015,9,1),date[-1])
```

I would like to have the `xlim` command inside the main plot command if possible, the dataset is really big. Suggestions?

Comment: you didn't provide assignments for count_a, count_b, count_c, count_d, or date.  Your dictionary assigns to 'a' twice and 'b' twice, clobbering the first assignment.

Comment: Oops, sorry that was just a simplifying-for-SO error, correcting it now

Comment: Old question, but why not applying the time range as a selection on the source dataframe *before* plotting, as such: `df_days[start:stop].plot(...)`? This will be faster than setting `xlim` (assuming you do not want a later change of x axis boundaries).

Comment: @Joël For me, this occurs because the limits are defined by the first series I plot (which only has data for the first three days in my month) and do not get extended even if the next series has more data; i.e., my plot changes x limits depending on which series I plot first, and the answer below produces a blank plot.

Answer (score 3):

Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/31500017/4893407 the following should work:

`ax.set_xlim(pd.Timestamp('2015-09-01'), pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01'))`

Are you sure the index of your df is a DatetimeIndex? Does it have duplicates? Is it sorted? Unsorted DatetimeIndex will cause slice indexing with Timestamps to fail.

Comment: It just comes up with a blank plot, although I know that that time period exists in the data. `date[-1]` gives `datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 30, 0, 0)` so yep it's definitely a datetime list. I haven't sorted it myself but all the data will already be in day-order with no gaps

Comment: If I run that example and change kind to bar it stops working. I am having the OP's issue as well.

Comment: true, the blank plot only appears for `bar` plots. has anyone found a solution?