# Trying to plot a graph with Pandas but only wish to display data from 1 row of a csv between two dates

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file of weather data.

I have the file indexed by date (e.g., the date of the reading).

One of my columns is 'Humidity' and contains humidity data.

I wish to use the .plot function but I wish to limit the data set to between two dates.

To discriminate by time I used this to view my rows,

london[london.loc[datetime(2021,3,1) : datetime(2021,5,31)]]

With london being;

london = read_csv('London_2021.csv')

My question is how can I modify this
london['Mean Humidity'].plot(grid=True, figsize=(10,5))

To only display the data between the two dates?

Comment: you can use `.set_xlim()` and `.set_ylim()` to try to solve this problem please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31500017/15042684

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
london[london.loc[start_date : end_date]]['Mean Humidity'].plot(grid=True, figsize=(10,5))
```

Comment: When I try 
`london[london.loc[datetime(2021,3,1) : datetime(2021,5,31)]]['Mean Humidity'].plot(grid=True, figsize=(10,5))`

I get a large error which ends with "ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not object"