# A problem with building scatterplot using dates and int values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, datetime

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

path = r'C:\Users\bossd\OneDrive\Документы\datarn.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path)
path2 = r'C:\Users\bossd\OneDrive\Документы\pipirka.csv'
df2 = pd.read_csv(path2) 

x = (df2.loc[df2['timestamp'].str.startswith('2015')])
y = df2['cnt']
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I wanted to build a scatterplot using dates that contain '2015' as x axis and 'cnt' parameter that means bicycles rent this day.
But after running the code i get this error

```
Cell In[47], line 14
     12 x = (df2.loc[df2['timestamp'].str.startswith('2015')])
     13 y = df2['cnt']
---> 14 plt.scatter(x,y)
     15 plt.show()
     17 display(df2)
...
File ~\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py:214, in UnitData.update(self, data)
    212 # check if convertible to number:
    213 convertible = True
--> 214 for val in OrderedDict.fromkeys(data):
    215     # OrderedDict just iterates over unique values in data.
    216     _api.check_isinstance((str, bytes), value=val)
    217     if convertible:
    218         # this will only be called so long as convertible is True.

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

The dataframe looks like this and containts timestamp as the day and cnt as the amount of bicycles rent this day

```py
data = {'timestamp': ['2015-01-04', '2015-01-05', '2015-01-06', '2015-01-07', '2015-01-08', '2016-12-27', '2016-12-28', '2016-12-29', '2016-12-30', '2016-12-31'],
        'cnt': [9234, 20372, 20613, 21064, 15601, 10842, 12428, 14052, 11566, 11424]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
    timestamp    cnt
0  2015-01-04   9234
1  2015-01-05  20372
2  2015-01-06  20613
3  2015-01-07  21064
4  2015-01-08  15601
5  2016-12-27  10842
6  2016-12-28  12428
7  2016-12-29  14052
8  2016-12-30  11566
9  2016-12-31  11424
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The `'timestamp'` column should first be converted to a datetime dtype with `pd.to_datetime`, otherwise the datetime x-ticks will not be correctly positioned and formatted.

  - The typical process should begin with cleaning the data, and then selecting.
- `x = (df2.loc[df2['timestamp'].str.startswith('2015')])` is the cause of the error, because it selects the entire dataframe, not a single column of the dataframe. And `df2['cnt']` is not selected for the desired year.
- `pandas.DataFrame.plot` uses `matplotlib` as the default plotting backend, and should be used for plotting the dataframe.

```py
# load the sample dataframe from the OP

# convert timestamp to a datetime dtype
df2.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df2.timestamp)

# select the data by year
df_2015 = df2[df2.timestamp.dt.year.eq(2015)]

# directly plot the dataframe, which uses matplotlib as the back end
ax = df_2015.plot(x='timestamp', marker='.', ls='')
```

[image]

- The x-ticks and labels will be formatted depending on the range of the data, which can be changed with the following answers

  - [Changing the formatting of a datetime axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43969396/7758804)
  - [How to change the datetime tick label frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45704659/7758804)
- The x-axis limits can be set as shown in:

  - [How to set xlim and xticks after plotting time-series data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31500017/7758804)